# Check if a value isset and true or 'true'

Tags: php

I'm trying to output a required string if `$required` var is set and equal to bool true or string true.

I have:

```
isset($required) && $required == true ? 'required' : ''
```

So with the following set:

```
$required = true   //required string set
$required = 'true' //required string set
$required = false  //required string not set
```

All good until:

```
$required = 'false' //required string set
```

How can I test the condition and allow for both string and bool types?

Comment: Use a strict comparison instead, `$required === true`. You experience that, which is what you're seeing. `true == "string"` is true, but if you use strict comparison, the types need to match as well (boolean with boolean, as an example).

Comment: @Qirel that won't work, I can't pass in a 'true' string - passing this string should evaluate to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `filter_var`...:

```
filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Would give you:

```
$required = 'false';
filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false

$required = false;
filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // false

$required = 'true';
filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true

$required = true;
filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN); // true
```

Saving the need to compare a bool and a string, so:

```
$required = filter_var($required, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
isset($required) && $required == true ? 'required' : '';
```

Further information for the random downvoter (hi r f):

Using `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` with `filter_var` will return the following, based on the input:

```
TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes"
FALSE for "0", "false", "off" and "no"
NULL for anything else
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
(isset($required) && ($required === true || $required === 'true')) ? 'required' : '';
```